# What word is abbreviated by "N" in names of destructive Lisp functions?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What word is abbreviated by "N" in names of destructive Lisp functions?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a direct answer [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983066/849891) [Linearity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410312/linearity)'s [link](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html):

> The *N* stands for *non-consing*, meaning it doesn't need to allocate any new cons cells.

Instead of allocating new cells, the old cells are reused resulting
in destructive/impure modifications.

Signalling destructive behavior is critical, but it's also nice to know that the non-consing variants are typically faster as they don't copy objects and leave garbage lying around.

The specific section containing this information is titled: ["Destructive" Operations](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html#destructive-operations)

Comment: The `N` in `SORT` stands for i`N`visible.

Comment: @Kaz perhaps the destructive sort algorithms they had in mind use cons in intermediate steps, resulting in conflict of whether to mark it with N or not.